# Creating 2020 in the fewest number of steps

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

You start with the number 1. You can create a new number by applying an operation on two existing numbers (can be the same). The operations are +, - and *. What is the fewest number of steps needed to reach the number 2020? **Bonus question:** can you find multiple solutions?

Good luck!

Comment: Are fractions allowed, e.g can I multiply 1 by say 2/3?

Comment: "You start with the number 1. You can create a new number by applying an operation on two existing numbers (can be the same)." - We're given `1`.  Where would these "existing numbers" come from?

Comment: It takes a minimum of 5 steps to get from `1` to a number ≥ 2020 so there's our lower bound. There are already several solutions in 7 steps. For any improvement, then, we're looking for a 5 or 6 step solution.

Comment: @SamAxe My question exactly. I am not even starting the puzzle, just trying to guess what the other number "should" be.

Comment: @Gnudiff: Yup.  This question is very poorly worded.  Think I'll skip it too.

Comment: @MindSwipe integers are closed under the allowed operations of addition, multiplication, and subtraction, so you can't get any non-integer values.

Comment: 1 step:

1

Then you just wait for, like, two weeks.

Comment: So, what is the second number to start with?

Comment: @Yola "can be the same" - meaning your first two numbers have to be 1 and 1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## All fewest move solutions

> 7 is the minimum number of operations

This should be all of the shortest length solutions, some of these have already been answered, and I'll leave credit to those that found them.

I'm also including the brute force python code that I used to exhaust all the combinations. That's how I was able to arrive at the the answer to the minimum length to be what it is.

### Solution  1

Found first by @hexomino

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 + 1 = 3 
>  3 + 2 = 5 
>  5 * 3 = 15 
>  15 * 3 = 45 
>  45 * 45 = 2025 
>  2025 - 5 = 2020

### Solution  2

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 + 2 = 4 
>  4 + 1 = 5 
>  5 + 4 = 9 
>  9 * 5 = 45 
>  45 * 45 = 2025 
>  2025 - 5 = 2020

### Solution  3

First found by @Jens

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 + 2 = 4 
>  4 + 1 = 5 
>  5 * 4 = 20 
>  20 * 5 = 100 
>  100 + 1 = 101 
>  101 * 20 = 2020

### Solution  4

Found first by @Benoit Esnard

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 + 2 = 4 
>  4 + 1 = 5 
>  5 * 4 = 20 
>  20 * 5 = 100 
>  100 * 20 = 2000 
>  2000 + 20 = 2020

### Solution  5

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 + 2 = 4 
>  4 + 1 = 5 
>  5 * 4 = 20 
>  20 * 20 = 400 
>  400 + 4 = 404 
>  404 * 5 = 2020

### Solution  6

First found by @hexomino

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 + 2 = 4 
>  4 + 1 = 5 
>  5 * 4 = 20 
>  20 * 20 = 400 
>  400 * 5 = 2000 
>  2000 + 20 = 2020

### Solution  7

First found by @sudhackar

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 * 2 = 4 
>  4 + 1 = 5 
>  5 + 4 = 9 
>  9 * 5 = 45 
>  45 * 45 = 2025 
>  2025 - 5 = 2020

### Solution  8

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 * 2 = 4 
>  4 + 1 = 5 
>  5 * 4 = 20 
>  20 * 5 = 100 
>  100 + 1 = 101 
>  101 * 20 = 2020

### Solution  9

First found by @Teejay

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 * 2 = 4 
>  4 + 1 = 5 
>  5 * 4 = 20 
>  20 * 5 = 100 
>  100 * 20 = 2000 
>  2000 + 20 = 2020

### Solution  10

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 * 2 = 4 
>  4 + 1 = 5 
>  5 * 4 = 20 
>  20 * 20 = 400 
>  400 + 4 = 404 
>  404 * 5 = 2020

### Solution  11

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 * 2 = 4 
>  4 + 1 = 5 
>  5 * 4 = 20 
>  20 * 20 = 400 
>  400 * 5 = 2000 
>  2000 + 20 = 2020

### Brute force search python code

```
def mdFormat(nums, ops, ans, sol_no):
    #Formatting the solutions for markdown
    subheader="Solution  %s"%sol_no
    subheader_lines='-'*len(subheader)
    steps = []
    val = nums[0]
    ans = ans[1:]
    for i, num in enumerate(nums[1:]):
        steps.append('>! %s %s %s = %s <br>'%(val, ops[i], num, ans[i]))
        val = ans[i]
    s = [subheader, subheader_lines]
    s.extend(steps)
    s.append('\n')
    return '\n'.join(s)

def apply_operations(numbers, operations):
    #Gives us the new list of number choices
    if len(numbers) == 1:
        return [numbers[0]]

    n_seq = (numbers[0], )
    n = numbers[0]

    for i, num in enumerate(numbers[1:]):
        if operations[i] == '+':
            n += num
        elif operations[i] == '-':
            n -= num
        elif operations[i] == '*':
            n *= num

        n_seq += (n, )

    return n_seq

solutions_found = 0

def search_n_operations(n, last_numbers=(1,), last_operations=None, choices=(1, )):
    global solutions_found

    if n == 0: #we're done with the recursion
        return

    if last_operations is None:
        op_combos = (next_op for next_op in ('+', '-', '*'))
    else:
        op_combos = (last_operations + (next_op,) for next_op in ('+', '-', '*'))

    for operation_seq in op_combos:
        num_combos = (last_numbers + (next_val,) for next_val in set(choices))
        for number_seq in num_combos:
            new_choices = apply_operations(number_seq, operation_seq)
            if new_choices[-1] == 2020: #This is an answer!
                solutions_found += 1
                print mdFormat(number_seq, operation_seq, new_choices, solutions_found)

            if last_operations is None:
                operation_seq = (operation_seq, )

            search_n_operations(n - 1, number_seq, operation_seq, new_choices)


n = 10
search_n_operations(n)
print "A total of %s solutions were found for %s operations"%(solutions_found, n)
```

Varying the n should illustrate where the minimum bound is.

> Outputs for n < 7: 
>  A total of 0 solutions were found for 1 operations 
>  A total of 0 solutions were found for 2 operations 
>  A total of 0 solutions were found for 3 operations 
>  A total of 0 solutions were found for 4 operations 
>  A total of 0 solutions were found for 5 operations 
>  A total of 0 solutions were found for 6 operations

Comment: Love your work! Deserves a tick. I think solutions 6 And 11 are the same.

Comment: Thanks! 6 and 11 are essentially the same, the difference is the second operation is addition in 6 and multiplication in 11. Whether or not that difference is trivial would reduce down some of the other solutions as well.

Answer (score 16):

> I can do it in 7 steps:
>  1+1 (2)
>  2*2 (4)
>  4+1 (5)
>  4*5 (20)
>  20*5 (100)
>  100+1 (101)
> 20*101 (2020)
>
>
>  Another solution (changing the last 2 steps):
>  20*100 (2000)
>  2000+20 (2020)

Comment: Wow very nice! Note there is another solution if you change the last two steps.

Comment: Extra solution added.

Comment: I like how your original solution ends by multiplying the two factors of 2020 that when summed together form the lowest number. This was my strategy but you beat me to it!

Answer (score 7):

Here are a couple of essentially different ways to do it in

> $7$ steps

**Solution 1**

> $1+1 = 2$
>  $1+2 = 3$
>  $2+3 = 5$
>  $3 \times 5 = 15$
>  $3 \times 15 = 45$
>  $45 \times 45 = 2025$
>  $2025 - 5 = 2020$

**Solution 2**

> $1+1 = 2$
>  $2+2 = 4$
>  $4+1 = 5$
>  $4 \times 5 = 20$
>  $20 \times 20 = 400$
>  $5 \times 400 = 2000$
>  $2000 + 20 = 2020$

Comment: Cool! These are different to previous solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution for

> 7 steps

Last steps essentially same as @hexonimo, missed by 4 minutes

> 1+1 = 2
>
> 2+2 = 4
>
> 4+1 = 5
>
> 5+4 = 9
>
> 9*5 = 45
>
> 45*45 = 2025
>
> 2025-5 = 2020

Jay's answer can be improved to 8 in another way

> 1+1 = 2
>
>  2*2 = 4
>
>  4*4 = 16
>
>  16*2= 32
>
>  32*2 = 64
>
>  64*32 = 2048
>
>  32-4 = 28
>
>  2048-28 = 2020

Comment: A random search on the given operations can be done like [this](https://gist.github.com/sudhackar/32e61ae4add3c2ce68af14f7095377fd#file-92053-py)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Jens's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/92055/20303), [hexomino's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/92063/20303) and [sudhackar's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/92064/20303) solutions:

> $1 + 1 = 2$
>  $2 + 2 = 4$
>  $4 + 1 = 5$
>  $4 \times 5 = 20$
>  $20 \times 20 = 400$
>  $400 + 4 = 404$
>  $404 \times 5 = 2020$

Answer (score 1):

> I can do it in 9 steps, and there are multiple solutions.
>  Example,
>
>     1 + 1     (2)
>     2 * 2     (4)
>     4 * 4     (16)
>     16 * 16   (256)
>     4 + 4     (8)
>     256 * 8   (2048)
>     8 - 1     (7)
>     7 * 4     (28)
>     2048 - 28 (2020)
>
>     or,
>
>     1 + 1     (2)
>     2 + 2     (4)
>     4 + 4     (8)
>     8 * 8     (32)
>     32 * 2    (64)
>     64 * 32   (2048)
>     16 + 4    (20)
>     20 + 8    (28)
>     2048 - 28 (2020)

Comment: I think you miscount 8 * 8.

Answer (score 1):

PARTIAL. Following the idea of @Engineer Toast, let us concentrate on the optimality part (which is actually the essence of the question: see "fewest").

> The lower bound is 6. It's easy to see that the highest obtainable numbers are in decreasing order: 256,81,64,36 after the 4th step. We can't use addition as the 5th operation, nor multiplying since 2020 is not divisble by these numbers, and 36 should be multiplyed again with a higher number than itself. So the remaining question: is 6 operations possible, or not.

Answer (score 0):

Jay's idea can be done slightly more efficiently in 8 steps:

> $1 + 1 = 2$
>   $2 + 2 = 4$
>   $4 + 4 = 8$
>   $8 \times 4 = 32$
>   $32 \times 2 = 64$
>   $64 \times 32 = 2048$
>   $2048 - 32 = 2016$
>   $2016 + 4 = 2020$

Answer (score 0):

7 steps:

> $1+1 =  2$
>  $2\times2 =  4$
>  $1+4 =  5$
>  $4\times5 = 20$
>  $20\times20 = 400$
>  $400\times5 = 2000$
>  $2000+20 = 2020$

The one above was already posted. This one should be new:

> $1+1 =  2$
>  $2\times2 =  4$
>  $1+4 =  5$
>  $4\times5 = 20$
>  $5\times20 = 100$
>  $20\times100 = 2000$
>  $2000+20 = 2020$

Comment: Looks like this one was already found: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/92063/60730

Comment: Yes, I see it after replying. The only difference is `2*2` instead of `2+2` but they are basically the same :)

Comment: I added a new one

Answer (score 0):

> 1+1=2
>  2^2=4
>  2*4=8
>  4^4=256
>  256-4=252
>  252*8=2016
>  2016+4=2020

Comment: You can't have 4^4.

Comment: 1+1=2 2*2=4 4+1=5 2*4=8 5*8=40 40+5=45 45*45=2025 2025-5=2020