# Creating 123456 in the fewest number of steps

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

You start with the number 1. You can create a new number by applying an operation on two existing numbers (can be the same). The operations are +, - and *. What is the fewest number of steps needed to reach the number 123456? **Bonus question:** can you find multiple solutions?

Here is a similar puzzle: [Creating 2020 in the fewest number of steps](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92053/creating-2020-in-the-fewest-number-of-steps)

Good luck!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found some 9 step solutions

1.

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 + 1 = 3 
>  3 * 2 = 6 
>  6 * 3 = 18 
>  18 + 1 = 19 
>  19 * 18 = 342 
>  342 + 19 = 361 
>  361 * 342 = 123462 
>  123462 - 6 = 123456

2.

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 + 1 = 3 
>  3 * 2 = 6 
>  6 * 3 = 18 
>  18 + 1 = 19 
>  19 * 18 = 342 
>  342 * 19 = 6498 
>  6498 * 19 = 123462 
>  123462 - 6 = 123456

3.

> 1 + 1 = 2 
>  2 + 1 = 3 
>  3 * 2 = 6 
>  6 * 3 = 18 
>  18 + 1 = 19 
>  19 * 19 = 361 
>  361 * 19 = 6859 
>  6859 * 18 = 123462 
>  123462 - 6 = 123456

Comment: Great work! This is the solution I had in mind. I wonder if it can be improved?

Comment: I am actually trying to simulate it on a computer. lets see If I find a better one.

Comment: 9 seems to be the lower bound for what I see from the simulation

Comment: I made a program to find all solutions and it didn't found the 8 step solution so nine step is minimum and 10 solutions exists

Comment: Yea. The closest I got was to get 6*(19*19*19*3-1) to represent in 9 steps.

Answer (score 8):

Minimum of steps is

> 9

I found 10 solutions:

**Solution 1**

> 1 + 1 = 2
>  1 + 2 = 3
>  3 * 2 = 6
>  6 * 3 = 18
>  18 + 1 = 19
>  19 * 18 = 342
>  342 + 19 = 361
>  361 * 342 = 123462
>  123462 - 6 = 123456

**Solution 2**

> 1 + 1 = 2
>  2 + 1 = 3
>  3 * 2 = 6
>  6 * 3 = 18
>  18 + 1 = 19
>  19 * 18 = 342
>  342 * 19 = 6498
>  6498 * 19 = 123462
>  123462 - 6 = 123456

**Solution 3**

> 1 + 1 = 2
>  2 + 1 = 3
>  3 * 2 = 6
>  6 * 3 = 18
>  18 + 1 = 19
>  19 * 19 = 361
>  361 * 18 = 6498
>  6498 * 19 = 123462
>  123462 - 6 = 123456

**Solution 4**

> 1 + 1 = 2
>  2 + 1 = 3
>  3 * 2 = 6
>  6 * 3 = 18
>  18 + 1 = 19
>  19 * 19 = 361
>  361 - 19 = 342
>  342 * 361 = 123462
>  123462 - 6 = 123456

**Solution 5**

> 1 + 1 = 2
>  2 + 1 = 3
>  3 * 2 = 6
>  6 * 3 = 18
>  18 + 1 = 19
>  19 * 19 = 361
>  361 * 19 = 6859
>  6859 * 18 = 123462
>  123462 - 6 = 123456

**Solution 6**

> 1 + 1 = 2
>  2 + 1 = 3
>  3 + 3 = 6
>  6 * 3 = 18
>  18 + 1 = 19
>  19 * 18 = 342
>  342 + 19 = 361
>  361 * 342 = 123462
>  123462 - 6 = 123456

**Solution 7**

> 1 + 1 = 2
>  2 + 1 = 3
>  3 + 3 = 6
>  6 * 3 = 18
>  18 + 1 = 19
>  19 * 18 = 342
>  342 * 19 = 6498
>  6498 * 19 = 123462
>  123462 - 6 = 123456

**Solution 8**

> 1 + 1 = 2
>  2 + 1 = 3
>  3 + 3 = 6
>  6 * 3 = 18
>  18 + 1 = 19
>  19 * 19 = 361
>  361 * 18 = 6498
>  6498 * 19 = 123462
>  123462 - 6 = 123456

**Solution 9**

> 1 + 1 = 2
>  2 + 1 = 3
>  3 + 3 = 6
>  6 * 3 = 18
>  18 + 1 = 19
>  19 * 19 = 361
>  361 - 19 = 342
>  342 * 361 = 123462
>  123462 - 6 = 123456

**Solution 10**

> 1 + 1 = 2
>  2 + 1 = 3
>  3 + 3 = 6
>  6 * 3 = 18
>  18 + 1 = 19
>  19 * 19 = 361
>  361 * 19 = 6859
>  6859 * 18 = 123462
>  123462 - 6 = 123456

Program which I made in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LowestPossible
{
    class Program
    {
        const int NUMBER_TO_FIND = 123456;
        const int MAX_DEPTH = 10;

        public static void Main()
        {
            var list = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
            list.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(1, ""));
            rec(list, 1);
        }

        public static void rec(List<Tuple<int, string>> row, int step)
        {
            var lastRes = row.LastOrDefault();
            if (lastRes.Item1 == NUMBER_TO_FIND)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", row.Select(a => a.Item2 + " = " + a.Item1.ToString())) + " <" + (step-1) + ">");
                return;
            }

            if (step == MAX_DEPTH || lastRes.Item1 < 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (var num in row)
            {
                var newRow = new List<Tuple<int, string>>(row);
                newRow.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(lastRes.Item1 + num.Item1, " + " + num.Item1));
                rec(newRow, step + 1);
                newRow.RemoveAt(step);
                newRow.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(lastRes.Item1 - num.Item1, " - " + num.Item1));
                rec(newRow, step + 1);
                newRow.RemoveAt(step);

                newRow.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(lastRes.Item1 * num.Item1, " * " + num.Item1));
                rec(newRow, step + 1);
                newRow.RemoveAt(step);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output does not have nice format but it was made only for me. Also code is optimized to run in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net), but originaly it was for [2020 question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92053/creating-2020-in-the-fewest-number-of-steps). It runs too long for this question so it doesn't work for this one in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net) due to timeout.

Comment: There are multiple duplicates here, you can minimize that to 5 imo - like 5 and 10.

Comment: Also is this the script? https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/92104/44046

Comment: I agree that getting 6 by 3+3 or 3*2 is nearly the same but it should be different solution since another operation is used

Comment: No it's not the script, I made my own yesterday for that question but I didn't have time to publish the result and when I wanted to do so today, it was already published... I'll publish it later today

Comment: Made a pretty substantial edit suggestion, feel free to reject and take parts if you like it

Comment: The edit is nice and saves a lot of space, but it is hard to see any solution at first sight. Also there were missing number of possible solutions.

Comment: The program only gets paths such that each step uses the last generated number.  That isn't required.

Comment: I removed the tick, because you don't find all the solutions, such as one without the subtraction.

Answer (score 7):

I've found a 10-step solution:

> ```
>  1 + 1 = 2
>  2 + 1 = 3
>  3 + 1 = 4
>  4 + 4 = 8
>  8 * 8 = 64
>  8 + 2 = 10
>  64 * 10 = 640
>  640 + 3 = 643
>  643 * 3 = 1929
>  1929 * 64 = 123456
> ```

Comment: Bravo. I figured out the 1929 trick, but couldn't make 1929 in few steps.

Comment: Math is hard, I agree. Seeing as how I sometimes calculate 0 times 3 = 3.

Comment: Waiting for sw solution to prove it is optimal solution or find better one.

Comment: Very nice work!

Comment: I think you could make it 9 steps, merging steps 2 and 3

Comment: @gustavovelascoh You can only use numbers you've already generated - the result of step 2 is useful later on, in steps 8 and 9.

Comment: You're right! I missed that

Answer (score 5):

I believe I can do it in 11 steps

> 1+1=2
>
>  2+2=4
>
>  4x4=16
>
>  16+16=32
>
>  16-1=15
>
>  16x16=256
>
>  256*15=3840
>
>  256*256=65536
>
>  65536-3840=61696
>
>  61696+32=61728
>
>  61728+61728=123456

Answer (score 5):

*On reflection I'm not sure this is the least steps, it's getting there though.*

**123455 steps**

> 1+1=2
>  2+1=3
>  4=3+1
>  1+4=5
>  6=1+5
>  6+1=7
>  8=7+1
>  8+1=9
>  1+9=10
>  10+1=11
>  1+11=12
>  ...
>  1+2023=2024
>  2025=1+2024
>  2025+1=2026
>  ...
>  123452=1+123451
>  1+123452=123453
>  123454=123453+1
>  123455=1+123454
>  123454+1=123456

Comment: You can save a step by using "+2" on the second to last step.

Comment: You can add a step by using "+2" on the last step and then "-1".

Answer (score 4):

Let's get the ball rolling.  I doubt this is the fewest possible steps, but it should give people a baseline to try to beat.

Total steps: 12

$$  
1 + 1 = 2\\  
2 + 2 = 4\\  
4 + 4 = 8\\  
8 \times 8 = 64\\  
64 \times 8 = 512\\  
64 \times 64 = 4096\\  
4096 \times 2 = 8192\\  
4096 \times 8 = 32768\\  
32768 \times 4 = 131072\\  
131072 - 8192 = 122880\\  
122880 + 512 = 123392\\  
123392 + 64 = 123456\\  
$$

Answer (score 2):

Two different 10-step solutions I found (without programming) are:

> 1 + 1 = 2
>  1 + 2 = 3
>  2 + 2 = 4
>  4 + 4 = 8
>  2 + 8 = 10
>  8 * 8 = 64
>  3 * 64 = 192
>  64 * 10 = 640
>  640 + 3 = 643
>  192 * 643 = 123456

and

> 1 + 1 = 2
>  2 + 2 = 4
>  4 + 2 = 6
>  4 * 4 = 16
>  16 * 16 = 256
>  256 - 1 = 255
>
>  16 * 6 = 96
>  255 + 96 = 351
>
>  351 * 351 = 123201
>  123201 + 255 = 123456

Answer (score 2):

A 9 step solution that doesn't use subtraction:

> 1+1 = 2
>  2+2 = 4
>  4*4 = 16
>  16+4 = 20
>  20+4 = 24
>  16*16 = 256  or  16*20 = 320
>  256*20 = 5120 or 320*16 = 5120
>  5120+24 = 5144
>  5144*24 = 123456

Another 9 step solution nobody has mentioned:

> 1+1 = 2
>  2+2 = 4
>  2+4 = 6
>  4*4 = 16
>  16*6 = 96
>  96-16 = 80  or 16-96 = -80
>  16*80 = 1280 or 16*-80 = -1280
>  1280+6 = 1286 or 6 - (-1280) = 1286
>  1286*96 = 123456

Comment: Beautiful and original! After seeing this I removed the tick. So it's back up for grabs.

Comment: My search found only these and the ones Jirka/sudhacker found (plus minor variants on those, such as swapping the order of 6/16).  However, I constrained my search to numbers between -140000 and 140000, so there may be additional answers that go outside those bounds.

Comment: My random [search](https://gist.github.com/sudhackar/32e61ae4add3c2ce68af14f7095377fd#file-92053-py) got these too, but somehow I did not minimize.

Comment: My code:

function rseek (ar) {
  if (ar[ar.length-1] == 123456) { console.log(ar+""); return; }
  if (ar.length == 10) return;
  var successes = get_nexts(ar);
  for (var a in successes) { if (-140000 <= a && a <= 140000) { ar.push (a-0); rseek(ar); ar.pop(); } }
}
function get_nexts(list) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var a of list)
    for (var b of list)
      rv[a+b] = rv[a*b] = rv[a-b] = 1;
  for (var a of list)
    delete rv[a];
  return rv;
}

Answer (score 1):

$6*6=36$
$36*4=144$
$144*144=20736$
$20736*6=124416$
$5*6=30$
$30*30=900$
$30*2=60$
$900+60=960$
$124416-960=123456$